# recursively grep through a directory, and extract the contents between the tags

Tags: recursion, grep, filepath, line-numbers

How may we recursively grep through a directory, and extract the contents specified below where the lines between the tags are located, i.e. line numbers and file location?

```
... < start > contents to be extracted
this line as well 
and this line
and before the tag < / start >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be `grep`, use that command:

```
grep -PzoHnr "(?s)< start >.*< / start >" .
```

**Explanation:**

- `-P`: Activate perl regular expressions
- `-z`: Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte
- `-o`: Print only matches
- `-H`: Add the filename in front of the match
- `-n`: Add the line number in front of the match
- `-r`: Read all files under each directory, recursively.
- `(?s)`: Activates `PCRE_DOTALL`, which means that `.` finds any character or newline
- `< start >.*< / start >` is the regular expression

**Alternatively**, here is an `awk` solution as well:

```
awk '/\<\ start\ \>/,/\<\ \/\ start\ \>/{print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0}' $(find . -type f)
```

**Explanation:**

- `/\<\ start\ \>/,/\<\ \/\ start\ \>/`: Finds all between `< start >` and `< / start >`
- `{print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0}`: Prints the filename, the line number and the line
- `$(find . -type f)` lists only the files in the directory recusively

Comment: No need to use find, grep can do it itself (see `-r` flag).

Comment: Your PCRE quantifier should be non-greedy, i.e. `*?` to handle multiple occurrences of the pattern in the same file.

Comment: @chaos, This is almost good, except the line number is incorrect. Is there also an option to print line number for every line?

Comment: @UrsaMajor use the awk solution i provided. The line numbers are correct there.

Comment: @chaos, if there is no space within the tags (before and after the brackets)
using 
      awk '/\<start\>/,/\<\/start\>/{print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0}' $(find . -type f)

prints the result twice. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: @UrsaMajor I tested myself, its not printing twice. Can you post your awk version and the shell you are using? Maybe that better? `find . -type f -exec awk '/\<start\>/,/\<\/start\>/{print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0}' {} \;`

Comment: @chaos, this is also printing other tags.
Can you check if it is happening on your side? How can we suppress the other tags from getting picked up?

Comment: @UrsaMajor please post the whole input, the command, the output exactly as executed and the version of your awk to http://pastebin.com/. Else I can just guess.

Comment: @chaos, this is what I see, when I copy and paste the command given:

    $ find . -type f -exec awk '/\<start\>/,/\<\/start\>/{print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0}' {} \;
output:
    ./C/a/b/c/scores.txt:9:<start> here
    ./C/a/b/c/scores.txt:10:and always
    ./C/a/b/c/scores.txt:11:end here </start>
    ./C/a/b/c/scores.txt:12:
    :
    ./C/a/b/c/scores.txt:18:<CustDetails>
    ./C/a/b/c/scores.txt:19:<CustName>Unix</CustName>
    :

As seen above, It includes empty string and irrelevant tags.

Comment: I used mawk, I think you have gawk: So this should work with gawk: `find . -type f -exec awk '/<start>/,/<\/start>/{print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0}' {} \;`

Comment: @chaos, this is perfect !
geee ... I wish I am as good as you. 

Thanks, chaos. I learn 1 more thing today.